# failing to check if document retrieved from cloud firestore database has data or not

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am retrieving data fro my Firestore and I can't seem to get my code to work. I want it to display something when it can't find data in the collection I gave it......................................................................................................................................................

Here is my code:

```
     StreamBuilder( 
                      stream: Firestore.instance.collection("payments").where('participants', arrayContains: userActive).snapshots(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot){


                        
                     

                      return Container ( child:ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                        controller: ScrollController(keepScrollOffset: false),
                        itemBuilder: (context, index){

                           DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = snapshot.data.documents[index].data();

                          if(snapshot.data.documents.isEmpty){

                               print("No Data!!!");


                          }else{


                            print("Found Data!!!");
                          }

                     /*   if(documentSnapshot["receiver_name"] == userActive )  {         
                                                            

                                                              
                            return Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32,vertical: 5),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
                            ),
                            child: Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.grey[100],
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(18))
                                  ),
                                  child: Icon(Icons.attach_money, color: Colors.lightBlue[900],),
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                                ),

                                SizedBox(width: 16,),
                                Expanded(
                                  
                                  child: Column(


                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      
                                    Text("Recieved", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, color: Colors.grey[900]),) ,

                                    
                                   
                                      Text("" + documentSnapshot["currency_received"] + documentSnapshot["amount_received"], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, color: Colors.grey[500]),),
                                   

                                   
                                     
                                                                      
                                   
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),

                                Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                  children: <Widget>[

                                    


                                    Text("+ " + documentSnapshot["currency_sent"] + documentSnapshot["amount_paid"].toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, color: Colors.lightGreen),),



                                
 Text(documentSnapshot["date"].toDate().toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, color: Colors.grey[500]),),                                
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          );


                      } else if (documentSnapshot["sender_name"] == userActive){



                     return Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32,vertical: 5),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
                            ),
                            child: Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.grey[100],
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(18))
                                  ),
                                  child: Icon(Icons.attach_money, color: Colors.lightBlue[900],),
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                                ),

                                SizedBox(width: 16,),
                                Expanded(
                                  
                                  child: Column(


                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      
                                    Text("Sent", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, color: Colors.grey[900]),) ,

                                    
                                   
                                      Text("" +  documentSnapshot["currency_received"] + documentSnapshot["amount_received"], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, color: Colors.grey[500]),),
                                   

                                   
                                     
                                                                      
                                   
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),

                                Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                  children: <Widget>[

                                    


                                    Text("- " + documentSnapshot["currency_sent"] + documentSnapshot["amount_paid"].toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, color: Colors.orange),),



                                
                                                 Text(documentSnapshot["date"].toDate().toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, color: Colors.grey[500]),),
                                
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          );








                        
                 



                      }else{
                                    
                                        
                                        return Text("Nothng found ",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, color: Colors.black));
                      }


*/
                                                            
                       
                        

                        },
                       )
                      );
                        
 }
 



  
   ),
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a new update to Firestore recently and you have to retrieve the value by using `.data()`.

To make your code work, you would have to change this:

```
DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = snapshot.data.docs[index]; //not working code
```

Add `.data()` in the end:

```
DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = snapshot.data.documents[index].data(); //working code
```

Comment: If I were you, I wouldn't assign `snapshot.data[index].data()` to a variable and call  `documentSnapshot["receiver_name"]`. Instead, do `snapshot.data[index].data()["receiver_name"]` so that your app uses less resources.

Comment: after i did it,  i get this error 
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Class 'QuerySnapshot' has no instance method '[]'.
Receiver: Instance of 'QuerySnapshot'
Tried calling: [](2)

Comment: ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'call'.
Receiver: _LinkedHashMap len:8
Tried calling: call()

Comment: can you update your code? My code is working but your .call() function doesn't exist

Comment: iv updated my code but  still dont see the print message whether there is or is no data

Answer (score 0):

check your `cloud_firestore` version, if you're using version `cloud_firestore: ^0.14.0`

```
DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = snapshot.data.documents[index].data();
```

if not use

```
DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = snapshot.data.documents[index].data; //this is a getter
```

data is a getter, not a method and should be called without parenthesis (javascript uses them because its a method there, but not in dart) but only before version 0.14.0. If you're not sure you can run `pub outdated` to check the current versions of your packages.

Also it could be better to change it like this

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: Firestore.instance.collection("payments").where('participants', arrayContains: 'userActive').snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot){
    if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active && snapshot.hasData) {
      if(snapshot.data.documents.isEmpty) return Center(child: const Text('No Data!'));
      print("Found Data!!!");
      return Container ( child:ListView.builder(...)); //your listView here
    }
    return Center(child: const CircularProgressIndicator());
  },
);
```

Comment: thank you, i updated my cloud firestore version to cloud_firestore: ^0.14.0 and everything else is working except "snapshot.data.documents.isEmpty" which is not showing the text  NO DATA  when i  delete data from my database

Comment: Its a text widget, not a print, it will only show it if the database return an empty query, does the query returns empty?

Comment: yes, I deleted all data from my collection, it won't find anything at all

Comment: Where exactly do you delete your documents?

Comment: From my firebase Google console

Comment: every time you delete one document you see the change in your app until you have only one document and then doesnt get empty? what does the listview looks afeter you deleted all, and have you checked snapshot.data.documents.metadata.isFromCache to cehck if its updating in real time with the cloud